# Simple proof that variance of variance estimate is $\sigma^4 \cdot \frac{2}{n-1}$ given normal iid sample

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

Let $X_1,\dots X_n$ be i.i.d. and $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distributed. Let 
$$\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ and 
$$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -\overline{X})^2$$

Then I know that through the distribution of $S^2$ one can very easily find its variance to be 
$$\mathbf{Var} (S^2)=\sigma^4 \cdot \frac{2}{n-1} $$

But given this result is everything i need, is it then possible to derive it using only elementary probability?

p.s. I didn't know what to tag the question, feel very free to help me out.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance

Comment: One answer to the question pointed out by @Glen_b (thanks!) applies even when the iid samples are from a non-normal distribution, and thus is even more beautiful and instructive.